# renaming all the files in a folder with python

Tags: python

I have a folder with files. I have to rename all the files but every 3 files.

I have this code:

```
for file in os.listdir():
    src=file
    dst=id_generator()+str(i)+".png"
    os.rename(src,dst)
    i+=1
```

How should I modify it? Or maybe there is another way

Comment: why every third file? Be careful here since os.listdir() is non-deterministic and the ranking of the files may change

Comment: `os.listdir` does not gaurantee order in which file names are returned, if the are in alphabetical order, use `sorted()` and then just at every `i+1%3 == 0` just use a `continue` statement given i is set to zero before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

you can edit to this.

```
counter = 1
for file in os.listdir():
    if counter%3 != 0:
        src = file
        dst=id_generator()+str(counter)+".png"
        os.rename(src,dst)
    counter+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Get all the filename into a list. Then iterate over the list, skipping every 3rd:

```
import os
from fnmatch import fnmatch

r = 'C:/folder_name/'
pattern = "*.png"

filenames_temp = []

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r):
    for name in files:
        if fnmatch(name, pattern):
            print (path+'/'+name)
            filenames_temp.append(path+'/'+name)

filenames = filenames_temp 


for file in filenames:
    idx = filenames.index(file)

    # Skip every 3rd item
    if (idx + 1) % 3 == 0:
        continue
    src=file
    dst=id_generator()+str(idx)+".png"
    os.rename(src,dst)
```